# When should I use the RSP register to add space to the stack?

Tags: stack, x86-64, nasm, intel, cpu-registers

I have a few assembly projects to realise and I am confused as to precisely when to add space on the stack and how much I should add.

I am using NASM version 2.13.03 on a unix system (macos) intel x86_64.

I have been reading a lot of documentation and did a lot of researching but none explain in a detailed enough way the answer to my question.
I understood the red zone and that leaf functions do not need the use of an increased stack.

I understood that increasing the stack by using sub rsp should be used before a function call and that add rsp should be used after the function call.

I know that on 32-bits architecture you use push and pop to increase the stack as you go but on this 64-bits architecture it is needed to use sub rsp and add rsp as well as the mov instruction to add registers on the stack.

If anyone has any tip or explanation regarding the use of the stack with this architecture and explain when to increase the stack and how much should be given, thanks a lot !

Comment: `push rbx` is totally fine on x86-64 to save/restore RBX.  If you're reserving space for more than 8 bytes of locals, and don't have a value to store there yet, then you would normally use `sub` instead of multiple dummy pushes, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes That makes it a lot clearer, thanks for your reply !! I still have trouble grasping exactly when it is necessary to push a value on the stack but I'll get to it aha

Answer (score 2):

Some [x86-64](/questions/tagged/x86-64) stack principles:

Stack needs to be **16 byte aligned** before function calls, according to both major calling conventions, including the x86-64 System V ABI used on MacOS. If it is not you're risking a Segmentation fault when calling external functions.  (Because they're allowed to assume alignment and use `movaps` for 16-byte copies to/from stack memory, for example.)

Fun fact - on MacOS, *system calls* do work correctly when stack is not 16 byte aligned.

For `push rax` rax value is pushed on top of the stack.
For `sub rsp,8` the top of the stack remains unaltered (so whatever was sitting there in memory will stay there).
The change to the rsp value is **exactly the same** for both instructions.

So for example you could do either:

```
sub rsp,16
```

or

```
push rax
push rax
```

And the stack pointer `rsp` would point to exactly the same place.

---

For moving the stack pointer by only 8, a dummy push or pop can be as efficient or more efficient than `add/sub`.  Beyond that, usually not.

Comment: This helped me a lot ! I still have a lot to learn but understanding this was important for me to be able to keep going, thank you very much !!